# Redirect para login en React

Tags: reactjs, login, redirección, jwt, router

estoy implementando un login en React utilizando un jwt que guardo en el localStorage y Express del lado del servidor, todo funciona bien, pero me da el siguiente error a la hora de usar Redirect:

```
You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>
```

He buscado en internet una respuesta, pero la mayoría de los ejemplos que he encontrado lo hacen de esta manera. Adjunto debajo el código de mi componente login. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import { GlobalStyle } from './Styles';
import { userLog } from '../FetchServer';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
   if (!err) {
    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
    var token = await userLog(values);
    console.log(token.data);
    if (token) {
     localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token.data));
    }
   }
  });
 };

 render() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const tokenParse = JSON.parse(token);

  if (tokenParse) {
   return <Redirect to="/home" />;
  }

  const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
  return (
   <GlobalStyle id="components-form-demo-normal-login">
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
     <Form.Item>
      {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
       rules: [ { required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' } ]
      })(
       <Input
        prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
        placeholder="Username"
       />
      )}
     </Form.Item>
     <Form.Item>
      {getFieldDecorator('password', {
       rules: [ { required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' } ]
      })(
       <Input
        prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
       />
      )}
     </Form.Item>
     <Form.Item>
      {getFieldDecorator('remember', {
       valuePropName: 'checked',
       initialValue: true
      })(<Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>)}
      <a className="login-form-forgot" href="register">
       Forgot password
      </a>
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
       Log in
      </Button>
      Or <a href="register">register now!</a>
     </Form.Item>
    </Form>
   </GlobalStyle>
  );
 }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: 'normal_login' })(Login);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedNormalLoginForm />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default WrappedNormalLoginForm;
```

Comment: No entendía el error hasta que vi la última parte de tu código. Normalmente ese error sucede cuando literal estás haciendo un render de `Redirect` fuera de un `Router`. Ya te haré una respuesta más elaborada

Comment: Te voy a agradecer mucho por la respuesta, no sólo para resolver el error, sino también para ver si entiendo de una vez esto de un Redirect fuera de un Router, es que todavía no me queda bien claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error es muy común y a la ves descriptivo: `You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>`.

Para explicarte un poco qué sucede, los `Router` de `react-router-dom` tienen un contexto, al acceden sus componentes (`Route`, `Redirect`, `Link`, etc). Dicho contexto, tiene la información necesaria para ser lo que es: Un router.

No puedo asegurarte si el patrón exacto que usa `react-router-dom` es `context` pero es muy probable, y aún así muchas librerías que encuentres que usan `react` lo usan, así que te será muy similar. Para que funcione todo esto, necesitan de un componenten `Provider` que es el que provee el contexto, en el caso de `react-router-dom` viene siendo equivalente a `Router` (que puede ser `BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter`, etc) y básicamente definen el comportamiento del enrutador de tu aplicación, cada uno tiene una aplicación distinta de acuerdo a las diferentes necesidades. Pero lo importante a destacar es que estos como *providers* deben *"envolver"* tu aplicación, de la siguiente forma, y tal como la documentación lo dice:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
     ...
     <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Esta es la estructura recomendada por la librería, que el router sea la base de todo tu proyecto.

Ahora, en tu caso, no existe tal router dentro del código, de hecho, no existen rutas definidas para hacer el `redirect` y esa es la razón de tu error. Para corregirlo, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import { GlobalStyle } from './Styles';
import { userLog } from '../FetchServer';
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields(async (err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
            var token = await userLog(values);
            console.log(token.data);
            if (token) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token.data));
            }
        }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const tokenParse = JSON.parse(token);
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        { tokenParse && <Redirect to="/home" /> }
        <GlobalStyle id="components-form-demo-normal-login">
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
                {/** Todo tu formular */}
            </Form>
        </GlobalStyle>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: 'normal_login' })(Login);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedNormalLoginForm />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default WrappedNormalLoginForm;
```

Como puedes ver, lo que hago es hacer el render del `Redirect` dentro del `BrowserRouter`, de esta forma ya puede tomar el contexto.

Ahora, hay otras formas de solucionar tu problema (siempre que estés en el contexto del `Router`) y es por medio de la función decoradora `withRouter`, la cual dota a tus componentes que no son hijos directos del router con capacidades para acceder al contexto del router. En la [documentactión](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) puedes verificar como funciona. Pero podrías solucionar tu problema con algo así (depende también a lo que estés implementando)

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export default withRouter(class Page extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
     const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
     const tokenParse = JSON.parse(token);

     // si hay token, redirecciona
     this.props.history.push('/home');
   }

   render() {
     // tu lógica de renderizado
   }
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias German, tu respuesta me fue de gran ayuda, ahora entiendo como tiene que estar todo bien englobado dentro de los providers.

Comment: De nada @ELLEO cualquier pregunta o inquietud que te quede, coménta y con gusto te ayudaré a resolver